# Optimal way to apply a conditional If statement

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm basically defining a set of parameters below in the `Start()` method. Most of the params will be the same except for the `request.Continuation` which can have a value of either `6` or `3`. My thinking was to have a list of the symbols that would get the value 6 (in `self.continuation`) and just say something like "If in self.continuation, value=6, else 3".

I'm fairly new to python so this could be way off but I wasn't sure if this would be a good use case for a `lambda` expression.

```
class BarsRequestSample(CELEnvironment.CELSinkBase):
    def __init__(self):

        self.symbols = ['CLES12Z', 'HOE']
        self.continuation=['ClES12Z', 'CLES6M']

    def Start(self):    
        for symbol in self.symbols:
            request.Symbol = symbol
            request.RangeStart = 0
            request.RangeEnd = -60
            request.IntradayPeriod = 5
            request.Continuation = 6
            request.UpdatesEnabled = True
            request.EqualizeCloses = True
            request.SessionsFilter = 31
```

What I know I could do:

```
def Start(self):

    for symbol in self.symbols:
        request.Symbol = symbol
        request.RangeStart = 0
        request.RangeEnd = -60
        request.IntradayPeriod = 5

        #potential attempt
        if symbol in self.continuation:
            request.Continuation = 6
        else:
            request.Continuation = 3

        request.UpdatesEnabled = True
        request.EqualizeCloses = True
        request.SessionsFilter = 31
```

I'm just getting an intuition that there may be a more concise way to do the same thing - would appreciate any thoughts!

Comment: FWIW, [Python style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is for methods and variables to be named lowercase with underscores: `Start()` should be `start()`; `IntradayPeriod` should be `intraday_period`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the list of symbols a set. Sets containment is an O(1) operation versus lists which are O(n). It doesn't matter for two elements, but it's a good habit to get into.

```
self.continuation = {'ClES12Z', 'CLES6M'}
```

You can use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) to condense the assignment to one line:

```
request.Continuation = 6 if symbol in self.continuation else 3
```

Answer (score -2):

For lambda:

[https://github.com/baruchel/continuation/blob/master/continuation/**init**.py](https://github.com/baruchel/continuation/blob/master/continuation/__init__.py)

```
"""
A module for adding a call/cc feature to Python.
"""

__version__ = '0.1'

__internal_type_error__ = (
    "Argument of a continuation must be a continuable function."
    )

class _Continuation(Exception):
    def __init__(self, f, args, kwargs):
        self.func, self.args, self.kwargs = f, args, kwargs

class Continuation():
    def __init__(self, calling_id):
        self.calling_id = calling_id
    def __callback__(self, f):
        if isinstance(f, _Continuation):
            f.uid = id(self)
            raise f
        raise TypeError(__internal_type_error__)
    def __call__(self, f):
        return lambda *args, **kwargs: self.__callback__(f(*args, **kwargs))
    __lshift__ = __call__

def with_continuation(func):
    def _w(*args, **kwargs):
        return _Continuation(func, args, kwargs)
    _w.__with_continuation_signature__ = True
    return _w

class _with_CC():
    def __call__(self, f):
        try:
            _ = f.__with_continuation_signature__
        except AttributeError:
            raise TypeError(__internal_type_error__)
        return (
            lambda *args, **kwargs:
                _with_CC().__callback__(f(*args, **kwargs)))
    __rshift__ = __call__
    def __callback__(self, f):
        k = Continuation(id(self))
        i = id(k)
        while True:
            try:
                return (f.func)(k)(*f.args, **f.kwargs)
            except _Continuation as e:
                if i == e.uid: f = e
                else: raise e

with_CC = _with_CC()
```